# Laravel Backpack hide 'edit' and 'delete' button if value is 'published'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

In laravel backpack v6, I want to hide the default edit and delete button if the value is published.

```
protected function setupListOperation(){
 if($this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->is_published === true){
   CRUD::denyAccess(['update']);
 }
}
```

But I can not access the is_published value in setupListOperation function. It shows 'Attempt to read property "is_published" on bool' error

I want to hide the default edit and delete button if the value is published

Comment: I have never used Laravel Backpack, but it has a [documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-api#getters) and it mentions something that may help you. It is very important that you read the documentation as it is stating what you can do and use

Answer (score 0):

as you want to evaluate "is_published" for each element, you need to add this check on vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/update.blade.php and vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php, there you can access $entry values and hide or modify the button.

Cheers.